# Single Sign On With thinktecture IdentityServer v2

Tags: asp.net, authentication, oauth-2.0, thinktecture-ident-server

I'm running thinktecture IdentityServer v2 with two Relying Parties in my qa environment on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

IdentityServer is configured for two RPs, one using Federation the other with oAuth

My first relying party (www.sitenumberone.com) is an ASP.Net Framework 4 web site using WIF Federation.

My second relying party (www.sitenumbertwo.com) is an ASP.Net Framework 4.5 MVC 4 application using oAuth.

When I attempt to access www.sitenumberone.com I am redirected to IdentityServer login and when I am authenticated I am redirected back to www.sitenumberone.com. This part works.

My problem is, once I have authenticated to www.sitenumberone.com, if I try to hit www.sitenumbertwo.com I am redirected back to the IdentityServer login page. I would expect it not to redirect me back to the login because I have already authenticated.

I have done some research and have not been able to find a solution to this problem. Do I need to set up www.sitenumberone.com as an oAuth client in IdentityServer?

I hope someone can help.

Comment: HelloWhat a re you trying to do is "share" STS token of one with two?

Comment: That's probably true, however I've long since moved on to other projects but thank you for trying!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add some `Auth Param` from your request site and also on `sitenumbertwo` authentication method.